# Display other column values only for distinct values in derived column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

These are my table structures -

1. Rule

[image]

2. Ruleset_rule_map

[image]

What I am trying to do is joining both tables based on rule.id and ruleset_rule_map.rule_id.

Want to fetch data like this-

[image]

If you can see I want to remove duplicates from derived column - rule_bucket.
**At the same time I want to display rule_order only for distincts in derived column rule_bucket**

Have written a query for the same -

```
select DISTINCT rrm.RULE_ORDER, CONCAT(r.PARENT_RULE, 
    IIF(r.CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('|', r.CHILD_RULE), r.CHILD_RULE),  
    IIF(r.SUB_CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('|', r.SUB_CHILD_RULE), r.SUB_CHILD_RULE), 
    IIF(r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('|', r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE), r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE) )
    AS RULE_BUCKET from [RULE] r 
inner join RULESET_RULE_MAP rrm on rrm.RULE_ID = r.ID 
and rrm.RULESET_ID = 'AAE97A62-F37E-4454-A008-FF40A102BB25' 
and r.PARENT_RULE <> 'N/A' order by rrm.RULE_ORDER;
```

but with the above query I can only get result like this.

[image]

Can some one please help me to write the correct query? Samples to help me solve the above are also welcome.

Comment: Images  of data really don't help us help you, especially when you then don't explain the logic either. Take the time to post the data in a **consumable** format, and include the logic behind it. Showing us pictures of the names of your columns don't help us know what your data looks like either.

Comment: What "consumable" format are you expecting the data to be in? Please let me know. 

I have asked the question above -> "If you can see I want to remove duplicates from derived column - rule_bucket. At the same time I want to display rule_order only for distincts in derived column rule_bucket".

Comment: Something we can copy, and paste, something we can *consume*. We can't copy data out of an image and it doesn't help those with screen readers. DDL and DML statements are best, however, otherwise you can use well formatted tabular `text`.

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks! Will update the question with data for RULE table and RULESET_RULE_MAP table.

Comment: @codingNubie . . . Your sample data still has duplicate rules, such as for rows 13 and 15, so your question still isn't clear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Apologies for the sample data. It was not cleaned properly. I do not need any duplicates for the output so your solution makes sense. I wanted the MAX(rule_order) so replaced the same in query and it works fine. Since your solution is closest to the output required I have accepted it as answer. Thanks for the invaluable help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really one one row per rule bucket, just use aggregation:

```
SELECT MIN(RULE_ORDER), RULE_BUCKET
FROM (SELECT rrm.RULE_ORDER,
             CONCAT(r.PARENT_RULE, 
                    IIF(r.CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('|', r.CHILD_RULE), r.CHILD_RULE),  
                    IIF(r.SUB_CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('|', r.SUB_CHILD_RULE), r.SUB_CHILD_RULE), 
                    IIF(r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, CONCAT('|', r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE), r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE)
                    ) AS RULE_BUCKET
      FROM [RULE] r JOIN
           RULESET_RULE_MAP rrm 
           ON rrm.RULE_ID = r.ID AND
              rrm.RULESET_ID = 'AAE97A62-F37E-4454-A008-FF40A102BB25' AND
              r.PARENT_RULE <> 'N/A'
    ) r
GROUP BY RULE_BUCKET
ORDER BY MIN(rrm.RULE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by RULE_BUCKET order by RULE_ORDER desc) as rn
  from
(select rrm.RULE_ORDER, 
        CONCAT(r.PARENT_RULE, 
               IIF(r.CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, 
                   CONCAT('|', r.CHILD_RULE), r.CHILD_RULE),  
               IIF(r.SUB_CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, 
                   CONCAT('|', r.SUB_CHILD_RULE), r.SUB_CHILD_RULE), 
               IIF(r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE IS NOT NULL, 
                   CONCAT('|', r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE), r.SUB_SUB_CHILD_RULE) )
         AS RULE_BUCKET 
    from [RULE] r 
    inner join RULESET_RULE_MAP rrm on rrm.RULE_ID = r.ID 
      and rrm.RULESET_ID = 'AAE97A62-F37E-4454-A008-FF40A102BB25' 
      and r.PARENT_RULE <> 'N/A') t) t
where rn = 1
 order by RULE_ORDER;
```